# Java Swing draw html formatted string

Tags: java, html, string, swing, draw

I want to create a `String` which displays the time in the format: `10h 30min`, but the units (h and min) should have a smaller font than the numbers. When using a `JLabel`, I get this work with a html formatted string with span attributes.

Now I want to add such a String to a custom object and write it with the `drawAlignedString` method. But, here the html passing does not working. The custom object than shows my code and not the formatted String.

Is there a way to get this working or any other solution for drawing Strings with diffrent Substrings?

This is what I've tried:

```
    String time = String.format(
            "<html>%d<span style=\"font-family:Arial Unicode MS;font-size:12px;\">h </span>  %d<span "
                    + "style=\"font-family:Arial Unicode MS;font-size:12px;\">min</span></html>",
            absSeconds / 3600, (absSeconds % 3600) / 60);
    g2.setFont(this.centerTextFont);
    g2.setPaint(this.centerTextColor);
    TextUtilities.drawAlignedString(time, g2, (float) area.getCenterX(), (float) area.getCenterY(),
            TextAnchor.CENTER);
```

Comment: Your question shows [no attempt](//idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you have made an attempt, you should edit our question to detail exactly what you did, researched for, and point to any links that were helpful but that did not answer your question. If you’ve tried to code a solution, that should be added in an edit. Your attempts should be turned into a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clear to read and understand. Also read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)

Comment: @chade_ I've now added the code which I used and which does not give me the excepted output.

Answer (score 1):

Once the label is configured, pass the `Graphics` to the `paint` method of the label.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LabelRenderTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

            String title = "<html><body style='width: 200px; padding: 5px;'>"
                + "<h1>Do U C Me?</h1>"
                + "Here is a long string that will wrap.  "
                + "The effect we want is a multi-line label.";

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Label Render Test");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
                    400,
                    300,
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                Graphics2D imageGraphics = image.createGraphics();
                GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(
                    20f,
                    20f,
                    Color.red,
                    380f,
                    280f,
                    Color.orange);
                imageGraphics.setPaint(gp);
                imageGraphics.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 300);

                JLabel textLabel = new JLabel(title);
                textLabel.setSize(textLabel.getPreferredSize());

                Dimension d = textLabel.getPreferredSize();
                BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                    d.width,
                    d.height,
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
                g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255, 128));
                g.fillRoundRect(
                    0,
                    0,
                    bi.getWidth(f),
                    bi.getHeight(f),
                    15,
                    10);
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                textLabel.paint(g);
                Graphics g2 = image.getGraphics();
                g2.drawImage(bi, 20, 20, f);

                ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(image);
                JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(ii);

                f.getContentPane().add(imageLabel);
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```